# highchart Sankey chart nodes flow with image for insights

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

highchart Sankey chart nodes flow with image for insights

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnDIJ.png)

Comment: Could you explain in more detail and prepare a demo version of your case? That will help better understand your problem.

Comment: in the below sankey chart looking option to add image in the from node to node as in the attached image   https://codepen.io/SophTooke/pen/ExorZZj

Comment: @SebastianHajdus  in the below sankey chart looking option to add image in the from node to node as in the attached image codepen.io/SophTooke/pen/ExorZZj

Answer (score 1):

Inside [nodes.dataLabels.format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.dataLabels.format) add images to node as on [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zf6yqpoe/).

```
nodes: [{
  id: 'Oil',
  colorIndex: 0
}, {
  id: 'Natural Gas',
  colorIndex: 1,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    align: 'center',
    varticalAlign: 'middle',
    format: '{point.id} <img src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png"></img>'
  }
}, {
  id: 'Coal',
  colorIndex: 2
}, {
  id: 'Renewable',
  colorIndex: 3
}, {
  id: 'Nuclear',
  colorIndex: 4
}, {
  id: 'R&C',
  name: 'Residential & Commercial'
}],
```

Alternatively, you can render the image using [chart.events.render](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render).

```
  chart: {
    styledMode: true,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        this.renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png', 60, 180, 30, 30)
          .add();
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me to fix the issue.